# Boost asio network disconnection handling

Tags: boost, boost-asio

I am using boost asio for my TCP Server, in this I am using async_read_some for reading .
Application is working fine when network is connected, normal connection closing are handled correctly like (EOF,abrupt closing).
   But my problem is I am not getting any error when network cable is unplugged. socket is open , and I get error when I am writing on socket. This is the way socket work. 
  Question: Can this is handled in Boost asio by any method?

Answer (score 3):

You may want to set "keep alive" on the socket, see [Socket closed notification](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/asio-Socket-closed-notification-td2598515.html). Try:

```
socket.set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::keep_alive(true));
```

Comment: Thanks. I used this with Windows specific Keepalive to solve this issue.