# Using boost::asio::tcp, how to get notified when socket connection is broken

Tags: sockets, tcp, boost-asio, keep-alive

**Scenario:**
I am using [boost::asio::tcp](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/socket.html) protocol between 2 peers connected over the network. My code runs on Linux, macOS and iOS.

I have a Watchdog ping-pong mechanism implemented on my both sides to check that the socket connection is okay between the peers. This is done by sending a dummy packet every 2 seconds which I think is a known approach.

**Challenge:**
But, is there are way I can avoid writing this watchdog myself? 
Is there a way to enable asio/TCP stack itself to do this for me and trigger an event right when the socket connection is not okay? I have been trying to understand the [kepp_alive](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html) functionality in TCP stack because it seems to have answer to my question?

But then again it looks like I can tweak the `keep_alive` parameters but `boost::asio::tcp` does not seem to give me an API to do that.

**Question:**
Will tweaking of the keep_alive parameters help me acheive my goal? My goal is to get a notification from the asio or TCP stack when the socket is not connected anymore due any wierd reasons on the peer side. Note that peer can go down in a weird way like kernel panic or something really crazy.

Just setting `socket.set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::keep_alive(true));` does not seem to help. The default time running on Linux is too high. I do get a notification even after many minutes after event of peer going down.

Comment: How does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22652293/boost-asio-network-disconnection-handling help my question?

Comment: You are right, your question is about tweaking and not about enabling it. You should be able to use the various `TCP_KEEP*` socket options though, see https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/#setsockopt

Comment: Ok. Let me try it out. Code described at https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/#setsockopt works on iOS as well?

Comment: *"works on iOS as well?"* - See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25725181/3081018

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that iOS discussion :-)

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Your comments helped me a lot. I think I am able to get this to work on iOS and macOS. Is there is a discussion on how to do this on Android as well?

Comment: Given that Android has a Linux kernel an these options are implemented in the kernel I would expect it to work the same as in "normal" Linux systems, i.e. as documented in the link I've provided.

Comment: Seems like `TCP_KEEPALIVE` and `TCP_RXT_CONNDROPTIME` are not available on Android? The code doesn't compile if I try to use them. May be I missing the correct header?

Comment: There are no such socket options in [the link I've provided](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/#setsockopt) for Linux. And I have no idea about your code so I can hardly tell what's wrong with it.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Do you mind taking a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58696319/tcp-keep-alive-does-not-work-if-you-switch-off-wifi-to-cause-an-abrupt-connectio ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use TCP keep\_alive property to get notified on the event of a unresponsive peer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58689857/how-to-use-tcp-keep-alive-property-to-get-notified-on-the-event-of-a-unresponsiv)