# How to use TCP keep_alive property to get notified on the event of a unresponsive peer?

Tags: sockets, tcp, boost-asio, tcp-keepalive

**Scenario:**
I have a client and server written using [boost::asio 1.63](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html). Generally the connection and communication part works well and great.

I have written a Watchdog on both sides which send dummy packets to peers in an interval of 2 seconds each. The objective of the watchdog is that the concerned peer reports a connection error if it does not receive the dummy packet it is expecting in the next 2 seconds. This is even more important for me because it might happen the 2 peers are not transacting packets for any user purpose but each of them is required to report a connection error if any of the peer goes down. The peer can go down even because of a kernel crash in which case it would not be possible for that peer to send a message. This is a classic problem of course which exists even beyond asio and TCP.

My Watchdog works perfectly well. No issues at all.

**But**, recently I read about the [keep_alive](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/#setsockopt) feature in sockets. I tried out the following code and seems like I can a property called keep_alive on the TCP socket by getting the native handle to the socket from within my code using `boost::asio`.

```
boost::asio::io_service      ioService;
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket mySocket(ioService);

int on = 1;
int delay = 120;
setsockopt(mySocket.native_handle(), SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &on, sizeof(on));
setsockopt(mySocket.native_handle(), IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPALIVE, &delay, sizeof(delay));
```

**Question:**
Above code compiles well on macOS, Linux and iOS. That looks great. But, how do I benefit from this? Does this give me a callback or event when the peer goes down? Does this free me up from writting the Watchdog that I described above?

I have used `boost::asio::async_connect` to connect to the peer. Can I get a callback to my connectionHandler when the perr goes down after the defined timeout interval?

Having set the `keep_alive` options, how do I then get to know that my peer is not responding anymore?

Comment: You don't need raw `setsockopt`, you can use [`mySocket.set_option`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/set_option.html)

Comment: `Does this give me a callback or event when the peer goes down?` I'd assume it fails with an exit code on your reads and writes.

Comment: So, It sounds like I still have to write the watchdog then. It wouldn't send me an event if my peer is sitting idle and not doing any read/write. Did I understand correct?

Comment: `It wouldn't send me an event if my peer is sitting idle and not doing any read/write.` Correct, but when would this happen? You'd usually _always_ have a read waiting for data, no?

Comment: TCP keepalive (a) is off by default (b) when enabled, operates by default at two-hour intervals (c) causes a connection reset next time you use the socket for I/O if a dead peer is detected.

Comment: Ahaa ! You mean it I have an infinite `asyc_read` and infinite `asyc_write` on both sides which I do :-). Then, the `asyc_read`/`asyc_write` would return out with error as soon as the peer is discovered to be down? Can you please confirm?

If this is the case then I am happy and I will try it out on my code to see if it works. You can please post it as the answer if this is really the case.

Comment: `Correct, but when would this happen? You'd usually always have a read waiting for data, no?` Yes. I do. I have an async_read always waiting for data. I should have done something wrong in the timeout values. I should get callback with error on my `async_read` then?

Comment: Thanks to all. I have got this to work. Now it is in the testing phase. I have one last question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58696319/tcp-keep-alive-does-not-work-if-you-switch-off-wifi-to-cause-an-abrupt-connectio if any of you guys have a suggestion.

Comment: @AdeleGoldberg I'm interested in how you got it to work. Could you write a (very) short summary as a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)?

Answer (score 1):

**If** the disconnetion was detected when an async operation is pending, your socket's completion handler will be invoked with the appropriate error code.

The problem is that TCP keep_alive option doesn't not always detect disconnects.

In general, there is no reliable way to detect sudden disconnection, other than by implementing application-level ping/heartbeat.

You can also see [this thread](https://sourceforge.net/p/asio/mailman/message/29070456/).

Comment: TCP keep-alive always detects a disconnect. The problem is that by default its timer is set to 2 hours of inactivity, after which it sends a probe. You can configure the timer to a much lower value.

Comment: @Maxim Egorushkin as far as I remember, I tried to do this (on Windows), and it still did not cover all the scenarios. Even if it does, configuring a *system-wide* parameter sounds suboptimal solution.

Comment: The timeout is a per-socket option on Linux, not sure about Windows. [More details](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/).

Comment: I tried tcp keep_alive on macos, android and ios. It seems to detect all disconnects for me. I have tested it quite rigorously. I think it works for me.

Comment: @AdeleGoldberg even if you "cut" the cable?

Comment: @IgorR. I haven't tried cutting the cable :-) But if I switch off wifi on one side then both sides surely detect the connection loss. Or if I switch off the ios device for example then the other side detects the connection loss. What else can I try?

Comment: @AdeleGoldberg well, "graceful" shutdown would close sockets. I had bad experience with keep-alive on some platforms (windows I believe), when a peer was suddenly powered off or a cable was pulled out.

Comment: I am not testing on windows. But I have tested scenarios like `killall -9 MyApp` or `pkill MyApp` on the linux side. This also worked well for keep_alive to detect the breakage.